# A, B, C uniformly distributed random variables. Find Prob(B^2 - 4AC >= 0).

Tags: probability, uniform-distribution

**Question:**

Consider three random variables A, B, C, jointly distributed such that all vectors (A, B, C) $\in [0, 1] \times [0,2] \times [0, 3]$ are **equally likely**. Find the joint density of A, B, C. Find the marginal densities. Are A, B, C independent? Consider the quadratic equation $Ax^2 + Bx + C = 0$. What is the probability that the roots of the equation are real?

**My Attempt at Solution:**

Since the vector (A, B, C) is uniformly distributed in the box $[0, 1] \times [0,2] \times [0, 3]$, the joint density is a uniform distribution.

$f_{A, B, C} = \frac{1}{6}$ for (A, B, C) $\in [0, 1] \times [0,2] \times [0, 3]$ and $f_{A, B, C} = 0$ otherwise.

Then to get the marginal densities, I simply indtegrated this joint distribution with respoect to the other variables, giving:

$$f_A = 1, f_B = \frac{1}{2}, f_C = \frac{1}{3}$$ 
over their respective intervals and $0$ otherwise.

My trouble is really with the last part of the question. For the roots of the quadratic to be real, we are looking for the probability:

$$P\left(B^2 - 4AC \geq 0 \right) $$

I was wondering how to compute this. My first thought was that I have to consider the product of two uniformly distributed random variables, or let $Z=AC$. Then find the density for $Z$, or $f_Z(z)$. Then, Find the density for $4Z$. Then find the density for $B^2$. Then, finally we can get the density for the whole expression $B^2 - 4AC$, which we can use to evaluate the probability. I am very confused as to how to get this result. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Since the joint density is of the form $f_A(a)f_B(b)f_C(c)$ it follows that $A,B,C$ are independent. Hence $P(B^{2} \geq 4AC)=P(A \leq \frac {B^{2}} {4C})=\mathbb E P(\frac {B^{2}} {4C}I_{B^{2} \leq 4C})$. We can write this as $\frac  1 3 \int_0^{3} \mathbb E(\frac {B^{2}} {4t}I_{B^{2} \leq 4t})dt$. But $\int_0^{3} \frac {B^{2}} {4t}I_{B^{2} \leq 4t})dt=\frac 1  4 (\ln t)|_{B^{2}/4} ^{3}$. Now use the density of $B$ to finish.

Comment: I am not sure that I understand your notation, what does E represent, and likewise for the I expression?

Comment: $\mathbb E$ stands for expectation. For any event $D$, $I_D$ is defined by $I_D(\omega)=1$ if $\omega \in D$ and $0$ otherwise. @EoinS